# How hadoop handle very large individual split file

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce

Suppose you only have 1GB heap size which can be used for each mapper, however, the block size is set to be 10 GB and each split is 10GB. How the mapper read the large individual split?

Will the mapper buffer the input into disk and process the input split in a round-robin fashion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The overall pattern of a mapper is quite simple:

```
while not end of split
  (key, value) = RecordReader.next()
  (keyOut, valueOut) = map(key, value)
  RecordWriter.write(keyOut, valueOut)
```

Usually the first two operations only care about the size of the record. For example when `TextInputFormat` is asked for the next line it stores the bytes in a buffer until the next end of line is found. Then the buffer is cleared. Etc.

The map implementation is up to you. If you don't store things in your mapper then you are fine. If you want it to be stateful, then you can be in trouble. Make sure that your memory consumption is bounded.

In the last step the keys and values written by your mapper are stored in memory. They are then partitioned and sorted. If the in-memory buffer becomes full, then its content is spilled to disk (it will eventually be anyway because reducers need to be able to download the partition file even after the mapper vanished).

So the answer to your question is: yes it will be fine.

What could cause trouble is:

- Large records (exponential buffer growth + memory copies => significant to insane memory overhead)
- Storing data from the previous key/value in your mapper
- Storing data from the previous key/value in your custom (Input|Output)Format implementation if you have one

If you want to learn more, here are a few entry points:

- In [Mapper.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/HDFS-641/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java#L134) you can see the while loop
- In [LineRecordReader](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/HDFS-641/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java#L133) you can see how a line is read by a `TextInputFormat`
- You most likely want to understand the spill mechanism because it impacts the performance of your jobs. [See theses Cloudera slides](http://fr.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf) for example. Then you will be able to decide what is the best setting for your use case (large vs small splits).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. I am mostly interested in the part of reading the split from disk to memory by mapper. Suppose we have 1GB split, while the memory of the mapper is 100 MB (The part which can be used to buffer input). Will there be 1GB/100MB times of accessing disk for reading and processing the whole split? Thanks

Comment: More than that. Basically the RecordReader only cares about the current record and will use the number of bytes of the current record padded to the next power of two (exponential growth). It asks the next byte to an InputStream like `DFSInputStream`. InputStream implementations use a buffer to limit the number of costly IO operations (disk or network), like a BufferedInputStream would do. The size of the buffer is controlled by `dfs.stream-buffer-size`. Images are gone by this [Yahoo! Blog Post](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/anatomy-hadoop-o-pipeline-428.html) can help you.